# js+html5 getUserMedia conflicts with microphone (android) (mobile thinks phone call is active)

Tags: javascript, html5-audio, audio-recording, getusermedia, mediastream

#### Edited - Update in bottom of post

I'm building a web based app for android using phonegap,
and i came across this problem,
after the initialization of getusermedia when i use the Volume down/up button the volume control is for call and not for speaker,
even if i didn't start a new recording...
in addition i noticed that the phone actually thinks its inside a phone call while the app is running for example:
i start my app , then i open whatsapp and try to record a voice message the message is being canceled.

I know that the next segment is the problem (i commented it and there was no problem)

```
/***recording audio block***/
function audioRecordingInit() {
navigator.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

    var constraints = {audio: true};
    var chunks = [];

    var onSuccess = function (stream) {
        $.globals.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        $.globals.mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
            console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");
            var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
            chunks = [];
            if(!$("#recordBtn").hasClass("private"))
                $.globals.lastRecorded.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            else
                $.globals.lastRecordedPrivate.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log("audio created");


        };
        $.globals.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
            chunks.push(e.data);
        }
    };
    var onError = function (err) {
        console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
    };

    navigator.getUserMedia(constraints, onSuccess, onError);// I think this is the problem
}
else{
    console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}
/***end of recording audio block***/
}
```

this  function is called after device ready

and im adding also the start recording and stop recording functions below

```
function startRecording(event) { 
  document.getElementById("recordingTime").innerText = "00:00";
  $.globals.mediaRecorder.start();
  console.log($.globals.mediaRecorder.state);
  console.log("recorder started");
  $.globals.timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
      $.globals.sec += 1;
      if ($.globals.sec == 60) {
          $.globals.min++;
          $.globals.sec = 0;
      }
      if ($.globals.min < 10) {
          if ($.globals.sec < 10)
              $.globals.timeText = "0" + $.globals.min + ":0" + $.globals.sec;
        else
            $.globals.timeText = "0" + $.globals.min + ":" + $.globals.sec;
    }
    else if ($.globals.sec < 10)
        $.globals.timeText = min + ":0" + $.globals.sec;
    else
        $.globals.timeText = min + ":" + $.globals.sec;
    document.getElementById("recordingTime").innerText = $.globals.timeText;
}, 1000);
   }
    function stopRecording() {
  if($(".circleNav").hasClass("recording"))
      $(".circleNav").toggleClass("recording");
  $.globals.currentState="Recorded";
  console.log($.globals.mediaRecorder.state);
  if($.globals.mediaRecorder.state=="inactive"){
      $.globals.mediaRecorder.start();
   }
  $.globals.mediaRecorder.stop();

console.log("recorder stopped");
clearInterval($.globals.timerInterval);

  }
```

startRecording starts when touchstarts on record button 
stopRecording is called when touchend on record button 
thank you for your help

## *Update*:

the conflict was with the microphone because the stream was always live and not only when recording.
now it works fine but still needs to make the record button disabled while in a phone call otherwise it will conflict and possibly crash the app or diconnect the mic from the all or maybe even disconnect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,
so after alot of reading about MediaRecorder,MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack.
I found the problem, the stream of audio stayed active and was using the microphone and in so denied me access to phone calls and voice messages in whatsapp.
I will add my solution below:

```
function audioRecordingInit() {
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
navigator.msGetUserMedia);
if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
    console.log('getUserMedia supported.');
    navigator.getUserMedia({audio:true}, onSuccessMedia, onErrorMedia);
    return true;
}
else{
    console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    return false;
}
}
```

notice that i made this function return a boolean value and i separated the success and error functions.

```
 function onSuccessMedia(stream) {
var chunks = [];
$.globals.mediaStream=stream;
console.log(stream);
$.globals.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
$.globals.mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
    console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");
    var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/mp3; codecs=opus' });
    chunks = [];
    if(!$("#recordBtn").hasClass("private"))
        $.globals.lastRecorded.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    else
        $.globals.lastRecordedPrivate.audio.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log("audio created");
};
$.globals.mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
};
$.globals.mediaRecorder.start();
console.log("recording start");
}
function onErrorMedia(err) {
   console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
}
```

here i moved the mediaRecorder.start() to the onSuccess function instead inside of the start recording...

and finely I changed the start recording function to

```
 function startRecording(event) {
     if(audioRecordingInit()) {
        //here is all of the visual changes
      }
      }
```

and that's it everything is working correctly